# jQuery: Detect if element exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In my code I have the following html that gets appended to a List Item when the user clicks on a specific element.

```
<span class="greenCheckMark"></span>
```

Using jQuery, how would I detect if the element existed, and if so, not add another green checkmark?

```
$('.clickedElement').live('click',function(){
//does the green check mark exist? if so then do nothing, else 
$('#listItem).append('<span class="greenCheckMark"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('#listItem:not(:has(.greenCheckMark))')
    .append('<span class="greenCheckMark"></span>');
```

Comment: Agreed. I like this as well. No **visible** tests needed. I wonder how the performance compares to a scoped selector or the find (looking at the source trying to figure it out -- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js)

Answer (score 1):

You could just look for it?

```
($('.greenCheckMark', '#listItem').length > 0) ? /* found green check mark in #listItem */ : /* not found */ ;
```

**EDIT**: Fixed 'un-relatedness' to question.

Comment: Eh, why use a conditional operator when an `if` statement would be better suited?

Comment: @J-P, that is absolutely unimportant. Still, if you want a reason, a ternary operator allows me to easily map the binary return of the condition in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "map"...? You're not assigning the return value of the expression to anything...

Comment: I realize that. But I'm explicitly stating BOTH return values. Honestly, what difference does it make? Please tell me how "an `if` statement would be better suited`. This is just an explanation to a question -- it's not going to be inserted verbatim into some code base.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickedElement').live('click',function(){ 
    //does the green check mark exist? if so then do nothing, else
    if($("#listItem span.greenCheckMark").length != 0)
    {
        $('#listItem').append('<span class="greenCheckMark"></span>');
    } 
});
```

Okay, after a few edits, this should be what you're looking for.

`$("#listItem span.greenCheckMark").length != 0` will return an array of JQuery objects, if that area has a length not equal to 0 then it exists.  Make sure that you are checking specifically for where you want to check, (`$("span.greenCheckMark").length` will check the entire document for green check marks).

Comment: @Eli, why `this`? - shouldn't it be `$('#listItem').find(...`?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, this will only append the `<span>` in the case that `#listItem` does not already contain a `<span>` with a `class` of `greenCheckMark`.

```
var listItem = $('#listItem');
if ( !listItem.find('span.greenCheckMark')[0] ) {
    listItem.append('<span class="greenCheckMark"></span>');
}
```

Comment: J-P - jQuery's `.has()` will always return an object. I get confused on this one because the method name sounds like it should return `boolean`.

Comment: J-P +1 I like your update. Requires fewer characters than `length`.